# How to pass multiple parameters to SystemUtil.Run using vbscript and UFT?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I need to call an Executable file that needs some parameters in order to be run successfully.
I am using SystemUtil.Run
I know the syntax to use it but I don't really get how to make it work when muliutple parameters are needed.

i tried sending all of them in a string

```
 systemutil.Run "c:\file.exe","param1,param2"
```

and with the hint given

```
systemutil.Run "c:\file.exe",[param1,param2]
```

also with a string

```
systemutil.run "C:\file.exe", ""&param1&""&","&""&param2&""
```

still I am not sure how to make it work.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the same command from command prompt by any chance?

Comment: @supputuri I can't do that, the script needs to be run from UFT

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
systemutil.run "C:\file.exe","param1 param2 param3"
```

If you have spaces in your param then use the below approach.

```
systemutil.run "C:\file.exe","param1""param 2""param 3"
```

Comment: I have tried that but since I am sending variables as parameters this is not working

Comment: How you are sending the variables? Are you warpping them with `Chr(34)`? Here is the sample. `systemutil.run "C:\file.exe",Chr(34) & param1 & " " & param2  & Chr(34)` how you have to do it.

Comment: Yes I am,     systemutil.run `code "c:\file.exe" , Chr(34) & param1 & "," & param2 & "," & param3& Chr(34)` , I use the colons, since I am sending the parameters to run a function